# og:image not come in face book debug

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I have use Wordpress-seo plugin by **Yoast**. when i share the [article](http://gititsolution.com/angularjs-development) on facebook there is no feature image come. so i have also [debug facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) then given **og:image blank**. you can also seen in attachment

[image: attachment image].

Suggest me any one.

Thanks.

Comment: The request for the image URL `http://gititsolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/codeigniter1.png` gets redirected to `http://gititsolution.com` with a 302 Found status code.

Comment: @CBroe : Thank you for replay. i agree with you and resolve the redirection but same problem faced it.

Comment: Facebook probably still has that redirect cached. Either wait a while, and see if the problem still occurs, or change the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

At times when the image is too small or server-protected to scrapers, the image does not display. The recommended image size is 200px x 200px.

Apart from this, make sure your `og:image` tag is on a separate line and give a space before the `/>` closing tag.

Try having a look at these for a fix.

Comment: thank your for response. i have also check with image size as you have given Also given space before closing tab.But both not worked.

Comment: Try adding the og attributes width and height to further specify with `<meta property="og:image:width" content="xxx"/>` and `<meta property="og:image:height" content="yyy"/>`. If this still does not work, visit [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) for any more info that might help